# Restart server without losing JMS connection

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have two app servers.  One sends messages to the other using JMS.   The sender runs on Tomcat, with ActiveMQ used inside a Spring Framework template method call.  The receiver runs on Jetty.

The problem is that when I restart one of the servers-- the receiver of the messages-- after it restarts it doesn't get any more JMS messages until the other server is also restarted.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  Is there a way to only require a reboot of one server?

The sender XML configuration:

```
<bean id="producerJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="simulationMessageSender" class="com.forio.simulate.activemq.SimulationMessageSenderImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="producerJmsTemplate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
    autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg value="com.forio.simulate.activemq"/>
</bean>
```

The sender java code:

```
public void send(final SimulationMessage simulationMessage) throws JMSException
{
    jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator()
    {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
        {
            Log.debug("Sending message: " + simulationMessage);
            ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(simulationMessage);
            message.setStringProperty("simulationMessage", "true");
            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

The receiver XML configuration:

```
<bean id="brokerContainer" class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean">
    <property name="config" value="classpath:activemq.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.url}" />
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
    autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>com.forio.simulate.activemq</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener"
    class="com.forio.simulate.activemq.SimulationMessageListener">
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <bean
            class="com.forio.simulate.activemq.converter.SimulationMessageConverter" />
    </property>
    <property name="simulationMessageService" ref="simulationMessageService"/>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" init-method="start">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="3" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>

<bean id="consumerJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using `SingleConnectionFactory`. each time `SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection()` is called, it returns the same connection, even after it is closed by restarting your receiving server.
Maybe `CachingConnectionFactory` will suite your needs as it has some recover on exception mechanism.

Comment: Very helpful.  What's a recommended alternative?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I meant `CachingConnectionFactory`. another solution is to subclass `SingleConnectionFactory` and override `SingleConnectionFactory.prepareConnection()` where you can attach `ExceptionListener` which will call `SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection()`

Comment: You can try setting setReconnectOnException to true on the SingleConnectionFactory. Assuming that your underlying connection throw a JMSException then SingleConnectFactory will reset the connection.